# Why does the :hover selector only work on the bottom of my <li>?

Tags: css, hover

When i hover over the top level menu items "(div > ul > li)" the following line of css only seems to work with the bottom half of the list item.

```
#header > ul > li:hover > ul{
    display:block;
}
```

When I hover over the top of a capital letter, the sub menu does not show, but the hovering over the bottom of the list item displays the sub menu.

---

Here is all of the code

```
<div id="header">
<ul>
 <li>
  <a href=""></a>
   <ul>
    <li><a href=""></a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href=""></a>                  
   <ul>                 
    <li>
     <a href=""></a></li>
    <li><a href=""></a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href=""></a>
      <ul>
       <li><a href=""></a></li>
       <li><a href=""></a></li>
      </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href=""></a>
      <ul>
       <li><a href=""></a></li>
      </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href=""></a>
      <ul>
       <li><a href=""></a></li>
      </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>

#header{
    padding: 0;
}
#header ul{
    list-style-type:none;
}
#header > ul > li{
    margin:0 2px;
    padding:0 5px;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
}
#header > ul > li > a{
    padding:2px 5px 0 5px;
    width:130px;
    text-decoration:none;
    display:inline-block;
}
#header > ul > li > ul{
    width:140px;
    padding:2px 0 0 0;
    margin:0;
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    background:#24B948;
}
#header > ul > li:hover > ul{
    display:block;
}
#header > ul > li > ul > li{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#header > ul > li > ul > li > a{
    color:#FFB5D2;
    padding:4px 5px;
    text-decoration:none;
    width:130px;
    display:block;
}
#header > ul > li > ul > li > a:hover{
    color:#24B948;
    background:#FFB5D2;
}

a {
    color: #003d4c;
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-weight: bold;
}
a:hover {
    color: #367889;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Comment: The code seems to work fine in a JSFiddle I made (http://jsfiddle.net/PgW4L/). Try putting text in the anchor tags, so things are easier to see. If you could, posting a screenshot of the problem could help too...right now, it's hard for me to visualize what you mean.

Comment: @Serlite thanks for letting me know there was nothing wrong with my code. There was a fixed position div with a height of 1%(cakephp debug kit) that was causing my menu items to not pop up when I hovered over the top 1% of the page. I changed the height to 0 and everything is working now.